# CUDA Manjaro Nvidia gtx 970 Bus error (core dumped)

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia, manjaro, arch

I get with this simple kernel an "Bus error (core dumped)".

Operation System: Linux-x86_64
Nvidia Driver Version: 525.60.11
NVML Version: 12.525.60.11
Kernel: 5.10.157-1-MANJARO
CUDA/CUDA Tools: 11.8.0-1

```
__global__
void add(char *y)
{
    int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;  

    int fac = 2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10*11*12;

printf("debug 0\n");
printf("debug 3 %d\n",fac);

    for(int i = 0; i < fac; i++){
        if(i % 1000000 == 0){
            printf("debug 7 %d\n",i);
        }        
    }
printf("debug 10\n");
}

int main(void)
{
  int N = 1;
  int M = N*6;
  char *y;

  // Allocate Unified Memory – accessible from CPU or GPU
  cudaMallocManaged(&y, M*sizeof(char));

  // Run kernel on 1M elements on the GPU
  add<<<1, 1>>>(y);

  // Wait for GPU to finish before accessing on host
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  
  // Free memory
  cudaFree(y);
  
  return 0;
}
```

It crash always at different times. `debug 10`will not be reached!

Has anyone an idea why?

Comment: The kernel is probably running for too long. Display GPUs have a driver imposed runtime limit to stop a compute kernel from freezing the display. Your code is completely serial. Try something less naive and see what happens

Comment: What do you mean with Display GPUs, do you mean the Card which manages the monitor or do you mean the Geforce family, which is not a professional computing engine?

I know its completely serial its just for debuging the error.

Comment: I mean the GPU which is driving a display

Comment: https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3029/~/using-cuda-and-x

Comment: on my v100 this takes about 17 seconds to run.  On a GTX970 it may take longer.  If you have a graphical X display enabled for the GTX 970 then you are running into the watchdog timeout.  The watchdog will terminate kernels that run for more than about 2 seconds. Furthermore, the X display system does not like being held off for long periods of time (seconds).   Read the above article for options.  This is a common topic reported on various web forums, you can find numerous reports like this.

Comment: (Determining whether X is enabled for this graphics card is not a simple matter of asking whether a display is attached or not.  It may require inspection of the X configuration.)